# Getting the text inside a div to be dead center (vertical and horizontal)

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

How can the text inside the white part of the box be aligned dead center (aligned both vertically and horizontally)?

See picture below:

[image]

The desired result is:

[image]

Here's the HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Centered Div</title>
    <style>

#wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#container {
    background: #FFF;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#inner1 {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#inner2 {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#titlebar {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 23px;
    width: 100%;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#0A246A, endColorStr=#A6CAF0, GradientType=1);
    color: white;
    line-height:22px;
}
#button {
     line-height: 10px;
     width: 18px;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-family: tahoma;
     margin-top: 1px;
     margin-right: 2px;
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     right:0;
}
#alertText {


}
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="container">

            <div id="titlebar"><div style="padding-left: 3px;">Information Box</div></div>

            <div><input id="button" type="button" value="X"></div>

            <div id="alertText">This is some sample text that will appear here</div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at `text-align:center` and `line-height`.

Comment: somehow like this may be - http://jsfiddle.net/W4XEU/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/w6Vc6/)

```
#alertText {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This works flawlessly, the only part I changed was height to auto.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only going to be one line of text you can do this:

```
#alertText {
    line-height: 58px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you going to have more lines of text you might need to do it some other way. Possible with `position`.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent project, I have coded this:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <img src="whatever.png">
        <p>Understand align</p>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .table              { display: table; width: 100%; height:100%;}
    .table .cell        { display: table-cell; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;}
</style>
```

Hope it is usefull. You can align a text or even a image inside the "cell" div.

Comment: this example deviated too much.

Answer (score 0):

this is actually harder than it looks. You might find this tutorial handy: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/14/justified-and-vertically-centered-header-elements/

Answer (score 0):

you can use padding :

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/parslook/PgEwF/2/

```
#alertText {
max-width:400px;
padding:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `div` to have a `display: table;` and use positioning to critically center the content within:

```
#alertText {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**This will also gracefully support multiple lines of text without any hardcoded or magic numbers.**

Here is the result:

[image]

[Codepen sketch.](http://cdpn.io/oawif)

Comment: throws the text where the titlebar is.